# Can `SUCCEEDED` be the last message for a Tor stream reported by Tor control?

Tags: protocol

I've been trying to fully understand what is happening with a single Tor stream. I can see in my logs Tor control events:

```
650 STREAM 97 NEW 0 my.website.com:443 SOURCE_ADDR=127.0.0.1:48828 PURPOSE=USER SOCKS_USERNAME="I2AU8MCE1OLH4GP158KU6" SOCKS_PASSWORD="0" CLIENT_PROTOCOL=SOCKS5 NYM_EPOCH=0 SESSION_GROUP=-4 ISO_FIELDS=SOCKS_USERNAME,SOCKS_PASSWORD,CLIENTADDR,SESSION_GROUP,NYM_EPOCH'
650 STREAM 97 SENTCONNECT 6 my.website.com:443 SOCKS_USERNAME="I2AU8MCE1OLH4GP158KU6" SOCKS_PASSWORD="0" CLIENT_PROTOCOL=SOCKS5 NYM_EPOCH=0 SESSION_GROUP=-4 ISO_FIELDS=SOCKS_USERNAME,SOCKS_PASSWORD,CLIENTADDR,SESSION_GROUP,NYM_EPOCH'
650 STREAM 97 REMAP 6 166.114.97.0:443 SOURCE=EXIT SOCKS_USERNAME="I2AU8MCE1OLH4GP158KU6" SOCKS_PASSWORD="0" CLIENT_PROTOCOL=SOCKS5 NYM_EPOCH=0 SESSION_GROUP=-4 ISO_FIELDS=SOCKS_USERNAME,SOCKS_PASSWORD,CLIENTADDR,SESSION_GROUP,NYM_EPOCH'
650 STREAM 97 SUCCEEDED 6 166.114.97.0:443 SOCKS_USERNAME="I2AU8MCE1OLH4GP158KU6" SOCKS_PASSWORD="0" CLIENT_PROTOCOL=SOCKS5 NYM_EPOCH=0 SESSION_GROUP=-4 ISO_FIELDS=SOCKS_USERNAME,SOCKS_PASSWORD,CLIENTADDR,SESSION_GROUP,NYM_EPOCH'
```

Now I know that `SUCCEEDED` means "Received a reply; stream established" per https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/control-spec.txt#n2426. But I have not found in my logs "CLOSED" or "FAILED" for that STREAM 97. Can it happen? What does it mean when there is no message following `SUCCEEDED` state for the stream?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be this way and it's OK: the circles/streams are recycled according to timeouts, "dirtiness" e.t.c... - it's all tweakable in torrc config file, so the stream that is in use can live for a while, no problem so far